# How to use directive in angular js. Not works in my case, why.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I need to print the dynamic html with click function bind. i have used $sce.trustAsHtml assigned to a scope variable. Following is my code for reference. I cant able to find why directive is not working in my case. Please help me out to solve this.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        .state('groupchat', {
          url: '/groupchat',
          templateUrl: 'templates/groupchat.html',
          controller: 'GroupChat',
          controllerAs: 'GC'
        })
    })
    .run(function($rootScope, $location, SharedProperties) {
      SharedProperties.sharedObject = {
        unread: 0,
        subscriptions: [],
      }
    });
```

**groupchat.js** // - controller

```
angular.module('starter.controllers')
.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
            ele.html(html);
            $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
          });
        }
      };
    })
.controller('GroupChat', function($rootScope, $scope, $sce, $compile) {  
    $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<span ng-click="testAlert()">Submit</span>');  
    $scope.testAlert = function () {
        alert('testing');
    };
});
```

**groupchat.html**

```
<ion-view>
    <div dynamic="trustedHtml"></div>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I'm not ionic-expert, but don't you need to inject `ngSanitize` in your module to use $sce? (And include the script of course)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div dynamic= "{{trustedHtml}}"> ??
```

im thinking if this were the problem, instead of hte var contents, it would be binding the string "trustedHtml" and it would be working/showing up still in your case however

Comment: When i use `<div dynamic="trustedHtml"></div>` it gets printer as `<div dynamic="&lt;span ng-click=&quot;testAlert()&quot;&gt;Submit&lt;/span&gt;"></div>`. i dont get any html rendered.

Comment: welp, you coulds avoid your whole directive "dynamic" and use the built-in ng-bind-html directive :/